# Use mathematical induction to prove a statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Use mathematical induction to prove that:

$$A\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n\left(A\cap B_i\right)$$

Comment: Please look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for a quick formatting reference.  There is also a link there to a much more in depth link that has (nearly) everything you might ever need to typeset.

Comment: @romanych: fyi, i think you are supposed to make some kind of attempt at a solution when you post a problem on this site.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint.** One may recall that
$$
A \cap (B \cup C)=(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)
$$ This is a key point in the inductive step.

Answer (score 3):

**Base case:** For $n=1$, this is trivially true since both sides give the same thing.

**Assumed true case:**

$$A\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i\right) = \bigcup_{i=1}^n\left(A\cap B_i\right)$$

**Inductive step:**

We use distributive rule to break it up first and then use the associativity of union of sets after application of inductive hypothesis.

$$\begin{align}A\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}B_i\right)&=\left(A\cap\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^nB_i\right)\right)\cup\left(A\cap B_{n+1}\right)\\ &=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n(A\cap B_i)\right)\cup(A\cap B_{n+1})\\&=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n+1}(A\cap B_i)\end{align}$$

Comment: just a nitpick but wouldn't $n$ have to be $2$ to use distributive rule for base case?

Comment: @underdog, right! sorry, I missed that. Let me correct it now.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the base step: n = 1,
$$A \cap \left(\bigcup^1_{i=1} B_i\right)=$$
$$A \cap B_1=$$
$$\bigcup^1_{i=1} \left(A \cap B_i\right)$$
which holds.

Now consider that the inductive hypothesis is true, that is, the proposition holds true for an integer $n = k$,

$$\color{blue}{A \cap \left(\bigcup^k_{i=1} B_i\right)}=\color{green}{\bigcup^k_{i=1} (A \cap B_i)}$$

Then prove the proposition for an integer $n = k + 1$,

$$A \cap \left(\bigcup^{k+1}_{i=1} B_i\right)=$$
$$A \cap \left(\left(\bigcup^{k}_{i=1} B_i\right) \cup B_{k+1}\right)=$$
Let us call the set $\cup^{k}_{i=1} B_i$ as $X$ for a moment,
$$A \cap (X \cup B_{k+1})=$$

Applying the distributive rule of sets to A over X and $B_{k+1}$ gives

$$(A \cap X) \cup (A \cap B_{k+1})$$

Substituting the original value of X in the equation yields

$$\left(\color{blue}{A \cap \left(\bigcup^{k}_{i=1} B_i\right)}\right) \cup (A \cap B_{k+1})=$$

Substituting the inductive hypothesis in the equation gives

$$\color{green}{\bigcup^k_{i=1} (A \cap B_i)} \cup (A \cap B_{k+1})=$$
$$\bigcup^{k+1}_{i=1} (A \cap B_i)$$
QED